# xslt: set readonly to a textbox

Tags: xslt

Is there a way to set readonly property to a textbox based on "if" condition?

```
Javascript:
      <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text" value="{//Doc/Value1/@name}"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

Like for the input tag,we have to set that property.

How do we do it???

Comment: I don't get the thing with the if-condition.. do you have an xslt if condition? Does xslt provide this textbox?

Comment: there was a indentation problem.Please check now.

Comment: You need a solution using Javascript or XSLT? (the tag is XSLT but you write 'Javascript' in the question text)

Answer (score 3):

```
<input class="text" value="{//Doc/Value1/@name}"/>
  <xsl:if test="someCondition">
    <xsl:attribute name="readonly">readonly</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</input>
```